# don't open Dialog?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to show a Dialog, I am using jquery ui with asp.net mvc 3.0

The problem is: no open any dialog only a white page. This my code.

I have a form and inside a link, it must be open the Dialog with data.

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Select Image", "SelectImage", "Image", new { @class = "popup-link" })%>
```

my SelectImage method do that

```
 public ActionResult SelectImage()
        {
            List<ImageLibraryItem> data = new List<ImageLibraryItem>();
            data = StateManager.SelectImage(ImageType.Flights);

            var datajson = new
            {
                lista= data
            };

            return Json(datajson, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

and return the images that I want show.

In the same view where I have my link (the first) I put this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.popup-link').click(function () {
            var href = $(this).attr('href');
            $('<div><p class="popup-content"></p></div>').dialog({
                autoOpen: true,
                modal: true,
                height: 200,
                width: 400,
                open: function () {
                    $(this).find('.popup-content').load(href);
                },
                close: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('destroy');
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

any idea!!! why show me a white page and not a Dialog!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a wrong overload of the ActionLink helper. It should be like this in order to for it to point to the correct controller action:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(
    "Select Image",                 // linkText
    "SelectImage",                  // action
    "Image",                        // controller
    null,                           // routeValues
    new { @class = "popup-link" }   // htmlAttributes
) %>
```

whereas you are using this:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(
    "Select Image",                 // linkText
    "SelectImage",                  // action
    "Image",                        // routeValues
    new { @class = "popup-link" }   // htmlAttributes
) %>
```